# Routing AWS IAM user to its own Linux EC2 instance user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

When I created my `EC2` instance, I was given a `.pem` private key file. I did it as the `root` user for my account. Then I created an IAM user and associated that user with a full EC2 access. When I logged in as that user, I was able to see the instance I created as root but when I went to see the connection instructions, they were the same as for the root, specifying the same private key file as the root. My instance type is `Ubuntu` so the default user on the instance is *ubuntu*.

My question is, how can I enforce that when a user connects to an instance, he is associated with his own host (instance) user? So if the AWS *root* logs into the instance as *ubuntu*, I would like the AWS user *awsuser1* to be logged into the instance as *ubuntu1*.

Answer (score 3):

When you create an EC2 instance, the instance will only ever be associated with a single key pair `.pem` file. That's as far as AWS will do anything for you in this regard.

Any user (IAM or root) will always see the same connection instructions. However, only the person with the actual `.pem` file will be able to connect as the main Linux user (`ec2-user` for AWS Linux, `ubuntu` for Ubuntu Linux, etc.)

To setup your EC2 instance such that it supports multiple users with multiple key `.pem` files, you need to follow these instructions from the AWS docs: [Managing User Accounts on Your Linux Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html). Note that this has nothing to do with IAM users or anything related to IAM. It's purely Linux administration.

Essentially the process is:

1. Sign-in to the Linux instance.
2. Sudo to get root privileges.
3. `adduser` to add the user.
4. Create a `.ssh/authorized_keys` with the public key that matches your desired private key `.pem` file.

Comment: If you need something less manual, you can use AD/LDAP, [Hashicorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/ssh/index.html), or a variety of other options I'm not very familiar with.

Comment: Something I particularly don't like is that the pem is downloaded only once upon instance creation and that it needs to be sent over network (email) to other users who connect to the instance

Comment: @amphibient the user may create his own key pair `at home` and newer send the private kay anywhere, but send you the public key only, which is not secret. Then you'll add that public key to `.ssh/authorized_keys` for newly created user and you're here!